# Dynamically create text alternative emails

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm using the `jinja2` templating engine to create both HTML emails and their plaintext alternative that I then send out using `Sendgrid`. Unfortunately for my lazy self, this entails me writing and maintaining two separate templates with essentially the same content, the `.html` file and the `.txt` file. The `.txt` file is identical to the HTML file other than containing no HTML tags.

Is there any way to simply have the HTML template and then somehow dynamically generate the `txt` version, essentially just stripping the HTML tags? I know a regex could achieve this, but I also know that implementing a regex to deal with HTML tags is notoriously gotcha-ridden.

Comment: Do you need to keep some formatting of this text?

Comment: Just the whitespace line breaks I already have in the HTML itself.

Answer (score 0):

I used this trick to get text out of HTML even if HTML is broken:

```
    text = get_some_html()

    import StringIO, htmllib, formatter
    io = StringIO.StringIO()
    htmllib.HTMLParser(formatter.AbstractFormatter(formatter.DumbWriter(io))).feed("<pre>"+text+"</pre>")
    text = io.getvalue()
```

If you are sure your HTML is well-formed, you don't need those `<pre>` tags.